Why must $S$ be extended to a complete set of sentences to prove the Model Existence Theorem
Model Existence Theorem: let $S$ be a consistent set of sentences in the language $L$. Then $S$ has a model.
The proof usually extends $S$ to a completely consistent set $T$ of sentences with witnesses.
I understand why the extension $T$ needs to have witnesses: in order for statements of the form $\exists x\phi(x)$ to be true.
That being said, why does $T$ need to be complete?

The construction is based on the technique of producing a maximally consistent set $\Gamma$ of sentences, and max cons is defined by (inter alia): for all $\varphi$, either $\varphi \in \Gamma$, or $\lnot \varphi \in \Gamma$.

You can and should answer this question for yourself. Modify the proof by omitting the completion step. Now work through the proof and find the first place it breaks. This kind of exercise (tweaking assumptions or constructions and seeing what happens to proofs) is extremely good for (a) getting a deep understanding of a proof, (b) developing your mathematical skills, and (c) doing research! Many new theorems can be proved by tweaking, breaking, and fixing existing proofs.
